# Display "has error" when any child item has an error

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to display a House and its rooms in a hierarchy, and I want to indicate whether any Room in a House has an error:

```
class HouseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ObservableCollection<RoomViewModel> rooms = new ObservableCollection<RoomViewModel>();
  IReadOnlyCollection<RoomViewModel> Rooms {get; private set;} // assume this raises PropertyChanged correctly

  ICommand AddRoomCommand {get; private set;} // assume this adds a RoomViewModel to rooms
}

class RoomViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public bool HasError {get; private set;} // assume this raises PropertyChanged correctly
}

<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Houses}> // assume Houses is a collection of HouseViewModel
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType=HouseViewModel>
            <TextBlock Text="Any room has error?" />
            <TextBlock Name="NeedHelpHereTextBlock" Text=????? /> // here's where I need help -- this should say True if any Room has an error
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Rooms}>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType=Room>
                        <TextBlock Text="Has error?" />
                        <TextBlock Text={Binding HasError} />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**How can I set the Text of NeedHelpHereTextBlock to True when any Room has an error?**

My first thought is to add an AnyRoomHasError property to HouseViewModel, bind the Text to that property, register an event handler to the ObservableCollection's CollectionChanged event and subscribe to the new items' PropertyChanged event, and update AnyRoomHasError if the PropertyChanged event is for the HasError property.

Is there a better way?

Also note that Rooms can acquire errors in the background. I.e. Room.HasError may change at any time, without user input.

Comment: You implement INotifyDataErrorInfo and pipe the results through the parent view model.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for me is to implement a SelectedRoom property, and every time this selected value change, the parent viewmodel will scan its detail querying for errors. No need to do event wiring and almost always you need to do something with the user selection, so probably you already have SelectedRoom implemented.

```
class HouseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private RoomViewModel _selectedRoom = null;
        public RoomViewModel SelectedRoom
        {
            get { return _selectedRoom ; }
            set {
                if (_selectedRoom != null)
                    NotifyPropertyChange("AnyRoomHasError");

                if (_selectedRoom != null)
                    _selectedRoom = value;
            }
        }

        public bool AnyRoomHasError {
            get {
                return rooms.Any(room => room.HasError);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for me because Room.HasError can change in the background, without user input. I have edited the post to include this requirement.

Comment: So, you need to handle PropertyChange event. In the event handler you only need to invoke NotifyPropertyChange("AnyRoomHasError"). The good thing of using this is that it will avoid a complex logic for AnyRoomHasError, It will abort the loop with first item with HasError = true